# SQL query to select pairs of values in a column 1 which match either one of two patterns in column 2

Tags: sql, postgresql

My data looks like this:

```
|User ID        |Install Version |
|--------------------------------|
|  Value A      |     Pattern 1  |
|  Value B      |     Pattern 1  |
|  Value A      |     Pattern 2  |
|  Value C      |     Pattern 2  |
|  Value D      |     Pattern 1  |
```

I want to select only the user IDs where 1 or more entries match `Pattern 1` and `Pattern 2`. So in the above example, I would only want to select `Value a`.

Basically, I want to compare which User Id's have installed both "Lite" and "Full" of a software product. For example, since `Value B` does not have entries paired with `Pattern 1` AND `Pattern 2`, I don't want to select it.

There will be many user ID entries but few installed Versions. I have played around with this problem for quite a while, but still I am having trouble with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two ways, one with GROUP_CONCAT and the other using subquery.

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(installed_version) as all_patterns
FROM your_table
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING all_patterns REGEXP 'Pattern 1'
AND all_patterns REGEXP 'Pattern 2';
```

--

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT user_id, installed_version FROM your_table
WHERE installed_version LIKE 'Pattern 1'
) as tmp
WHERE installed_version LIKE 'Pattern 2';
```

Comment: Exaclty my feeling when I found this method :)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe . . . The second simply doesn't work.  The first doesn't work in Postgres.  I have no idea why this would be upvoted, unless a MySQL tag was removed at some point.

Comment: I agree with the first method - it works perfectly when applied to my data. I never knew about INTERSECT

Answer (score 1):

The table is not clearly defined, but in principle the query could look similar to this:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM installation
WHERE version = 'version 1'
INTERSECT
SELECT user_id
FROM installation
WHERE version = 'version 2';
```

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, I would go for:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM t
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE installed_version = 'Pattern 1') > 0 AND
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE installed_version = 'Pattern 2') > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use intersect to get which has both pattern 1 and pattern 2

```
SELECT [User ID]
FROM Table
WHERE [Install Version]='Pattern 1'
INTERSECT
SELECT [User ID]
FROM Table
WHERE [Install Version]='Pattern 2';
```