# MySQL condition statement across multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have a Profile table like this

```
|--------|-----------|
| People | Favorite  |
|--------|-----------|
|   A    |   Movie   |
|   B    |   Movie   |
|   B    |  Jogging  |
|--------|-----------|
```

Q: How to retrieve the people whose favorite is movie but not jogging?

In this table, the result is only People A.

Although I came out with this

```
select People from Profile
where
People
in
(select People from Profile
where favorite='Movie')
and
People
not in
(select People from Profile
where favorite='Jogging')
```

But it seem like can be better, any suggestion or answer (without using join or union clause)?

Comment: be very careful with the `NOT IN (subquery)` pattern. If the resultset from the subquery contains a NULL, the behavior may not be what the uninitiated expect. I would include `and People IS NOT NULL` in the subquery, to make explicit the gurantee that the subquery won't return a NULL value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rboiDpxxbABCpjtduEz7uY/1

```
SELECT People 
FROM `profile`
GROUP BY people
HAVING SUM('Movie' = favorite) > 0
   AND SUM('Jogging' = favorite) = 0
```

Comment: @symcbean I'm not understand about it, could you provide the counter example?

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of ways. While you can use a UNION, its rather messy and innefficient. MySQL doesn't have a [MINUS](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php) clause which would give a fairly easy to understand query.

You could aggregate the data:

```
SELECT people
, MAX(IF(favorite='jogging', 1, 0)) as jogging
, MAX(IF(favorite='movie', 1, 0)) as movie
FROM profile
GROUP BY people
HAVING movie=1 AND jogging=0
```

Or use an outer join:

```
SELECT m.people
FROM profile m
LEFT JOIN
 ( SELECT j.people
 FROM joggers j
 WHERE j.favorite='jogging' ) joggers
ON m.people=joggers.people
WHERE joggers.people IS NULL
AND m.favorite='movies'
```

Using a NOT IN/NOT EXISTS gives clearer syntax but again would be very innefficient.

Answer (score 0):

There are several query patterns that will return a result that satisfies the specification.

We can use `NOT EXISTS` with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT p.people 
  FROM profile p 
 WHERE p.favorite = 'Movie' 
   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                      FROM profile q
                     WHERE q.favorite = 'Jogging' 
                       AND q.people   = p.people   /* related to row in out query */
                  )
 ORDER
    BY p.people
```

---

An equivalent result can also be done with an *anti-join* pattern:

```
SELECT p.people 
  FROM profile p
  LEFT
  JOIN profile q
    ON q.people   = p.people
   AND q.favorite = 'Jogging'
 WHERE q.people IS NULL
   AND p.favorite = 'Movie'
 ORDER BY p.people
```

---

Another option is *conditional aggregation*. Without a guarantee about uniqueness, and some MySQL shorthand:

```
SELECT p.people
  FROM profile p
 GROUP
    BY p.people
HAVING 1 = MAX(p.favorite='Movie')
   AND 0 = MAX(p.favorite='Jogging')
```

A more portable more ANSI standard compliant syntax for the conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT p.people
  FROM profile p
 GROUP
    BY p.people
HAVING 1 = MAX(CASE p.favorite WHEN 'Movie'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   AND 0 = MAX(CASE p.favorite WHEN Jogging' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem when you want to have multiple conditions with the same column. I have answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55233121/sql-query-to-select-pairs-of-values-in-a-column-1-which-match-either-one-of-two/55233396#55233396) and there are other methods like intersect and subqueries.

```
SELECT people, GROUP_CONCAT(favorite) as fav
FROM profile
GROUP BY people
HAVING fav REGEXP 'Movie'
AND NOT fav REGEXP 'Jogging';
```

Answer (score 0):

With `group by people` and checking the minimum and maximum values of `favorite` to be `'Movie'`:

```
select people from tablename
where favorite in ('Movie', 'Jogging')
group by people
having min(favorite) = 'Movie' and max(favorite) = 'Movie'
```